# Is ".after()" jQuery or can I use it in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, element

What is the reason I don't have to include the jQuery library. To use the method. I want to append an element after the `h1`.

The `h1` is in between other child elements.

```
const contentDivH1 = document.getElementById('content').children[2];
const svgElement = document.createElement('svg');
```

iife to append after `h1` the `svg` element

```
(() => contentDivH1.after(svgElement))()
```

It worked but why?

thanks to @Quentin: `.after()` is part of the DOM API, not native JS.

Comment: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/after

Comment: It's part of JS but [it's experimental](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/after)

Comment: @VLAZ — That's part of the DOM API, not native JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.after()` is a method. If it exists or not depends entirely on what object you are calling it on.

There is an [`after` method defined in jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/after/).

There is also an [`after` method defined in DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/after), although it is experimental.

They two methods behave **differently**.